# Effect of Superposition Principle on Statistics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

In statistical mechanics, a system is supposedly at some point in phase space, but we don't know which. For this reason, we describe it by some macroscopic variables, and any point in phase space that fits this description is a possibility.

Quantum mechanics tells us that a system of particles is naturally in superposition, so many of the phase space possibilities for a given system, perhaps all of them, are realized at the same time.  Does this not have some effect on the statistics?  I think I am just alluding to the density operator and the usual way that a macrostate gets specified in quantum statistics, but just checking.

Comment: Yes, you are referring to the density operator.

Comment: The superposition principle doesn't involve a superposition of points in *phase space*. Any single term in such a superposition would violate the uncertainty principle. In quantum theory, position and momentum are non-commuting observables, and the Hilbert space does not have any states with strictly well-defined values of both. That is, there are no microstates corresponding to the classical concept of a "point in phase space." Using a density matrix doesn't change this. A density matrix *is* used to represent an ensemble of microstates, but the classical phase-space concept does not apply.

Comment: This all sounds correct but what about the possibility of a quantum equilibrium where all the phase space microstates are in actual superposition, and so the macrostate is the complete description of the system?